# set user session in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = "johndoe" // Must be already set
        ?>
```

How to write equivalent code for the above in django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When SessionMiddleware is activated, each HttpRequest object – the first argument to any Django view function – will have a session attribute, which is a dictionary-like object. You can read it and write to it.

[Read more ...](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions)

---

Example:

```
def login(request):
    m = Member.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
    if m.password == request.POST['password']:
        request.session['member_id'] = m.id
        return HttpResponse("You're logged in.")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Your username and password didn't match.")
```